# Flask session variables disappear when using remote server tunnelling

Tags: python, session, flask, session-cookies

I am trying to use session variables in a flask application like follows:

```
from flask import Flask, session
from flask import request
from flask import render_template
from flask import redirect, url_for

app = Flask(__name__)

app.secret_key = 'verysecretindeed'

@app.route('/')
def myform():
    session['ax'] = 42
    return render_template("test1.html", session=session)

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def modifyvalue():

    incr = request.form('incr')
    a = session['ax']
    if incr == '1':
         a = a + 1
    session['ax']=a
    return render_template("test1.html", session=session)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

This code works fine on my local machine.

Now, I run the code on a remote server and tunnel the remote server's localhost to my localhost in the following way:

```
ssh -N -f -L localhost:5000:localhost:5000 <username>@<server>.blah.edu
```

Now, when I run this code, after getting the "incr" request from the webpage, I get:

keyerror: 'ax' inside the modifyvalue() function.

When I print the session inside the myform() function, the values are there. However, when I print the session in the `modifyvalue()` function, the session is empty.

I have tried setting APPLICATION_ROOT like:

```
app.config['APPLICATION_ROOT']= '/path/to/code/'
```

I have tried other browsers, incognito, nothing seems to work.
I tried clearing the session first in myform() as well. My app.secret_key is just a static string value.

Any idea what might be going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Two view function you have, first one add a value to session the other one edit this value, they are use same url so you can combine them. Well if you say I am posting the form then check for post method

```
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def home():
    session['ax'] = 42
    if request.method == 'POST':
        incr = request.form('incr')
        a = session['ax']
        if incr == '1':
            a = a + 1
        session['ax'] = a
    return render_template("test1.html", session=session)
```